# Option file feature is not working in sqoop if we keep option file in hdfs

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to use the option file feature of `sqoop`. When I keep the option file in local file system, `sqoop` import command is working properly.
But when I try to access the same option file from `hdfs` it is giving me the following error:

> ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Error while expanding arguments
>   java.lang.Exception: Unable to read options file:

In the `sqoop` user guide it is mentioned that a password file can be used from `hdfs` path then why can't an option file be used?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the sample of the code where it is working and where it is not?

Comment: I tried with Simple sqoop command with option file ,it is working on local with the command:    
sqoop --options-file /home/dev/optionsfile.txt --table Sample           
           
Not working when we keep option file on hdfs path like below:
sqoop --options-file /user/ingestiondev/optionsfile.txt --table Sample

Comment: what is the content of the options file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with putting the 'hdfs://' prefix before the file like below. Ensure to copy the file to hdfs in this location. -

```
sqoop --options-file hdfs://user/ingestiondev/optionsfile.txt --table Sample
```

Comment: I have tried this also. It is giving same error. "Unable to expand arguments". Can you please share results if you have done this before from hdfs